# How to replace PM & AM in html input-time with icons or words

Tags: html, input, time

I want to translate **PM** A& **AM** in input time type to arabic or any other language or replace it with icons as example change PM=X and AM=Y

html

```
 <label for="first" class="">{{__('From Hour')}}</label>
   <input type="time" class="form-control input-md"name="" id="from_hour" value="">
```

This Image to be more understandable  :

[image]

Comment: Have u found a resolve?

Comment: @HackerMF not yet do you have a solution?

Comment: Nope unfortunately